# Convert 3D model into 2D images

Tags: 3d

Is there a way I can convert 3D models in maya/3ds max/blender/Autocad into bunch of 2D images ?

Thanks

Comment: Down-voted: not android related (if it is, you didn't make the connection.)

Comment: I am coding my application in android and want to use 2D images which are 3D model. I saw that there I some 3D android game engines which provides such features for games. Sorry if I did mistake posting it inside android category.

Comment: Alright, wasn't sure whether or not it was a mistake. Downvote withdrawn.

Answer (score 2):

Im 3ds Max you would arrange the camera view of you model in the viewport of your choice, 
then press the render button on the top bar, it looks like a teapot.

In the render window that open you can define:
 - The range of frames you want to output, or a single frame
 - The size in pixels of the render output
 - Many other options...

Then press the Save As... button down the window and select the file format you want to output. If you are outputting an animation Max will add sequential numbers to the end of the file name.

Press the Render button at the bottom and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Most tools have an export function but SO isn't the place to ask such a broad question. I know blender has an export-image-per-frame script that you can use.

What does this have to do with Android?

Comment: Blender creates sprites from a 3D model with animation.

Imagine my model is very big and say for example a shopping mall and I am given a 3D model of a shopping center and I want bunch of 2D images of all sides of mall including the top view and malls side view and walkway inside the mall between the shops.

How can I get the bunch of 2D images for this 3D model ?